# Android: Admob doesn't work on multiple pages?

Tags: android, admob

I was able to setup admob in my app but it only shows in the first page where i first setup.  I copied same code on different activity and layout but these never appear.  Any idea why? and is it possible to display admob on different layout xml?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see this working in the way you describe it in other ways, so I guess it should definitely be possible to have Ads on multiple pages.

Have you tried putting your ads into test mode- do they appear by then? If not you probably have a different problem (like layout etc..)

http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android